# Reactjs: setState always fails and returns undefined in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Having strange errors using setState(), I always get nothing set to state:

Error code:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined(…)

```
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {listings:[]};
};

componentDidMount (){
    fetch('./javascripts/data.json').then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function(json) {
       console.log('parsed json ', json.listings);
        this.setState({listings: 'test string'});
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
render () {
    return (
        <ListingUser userData={this.state.listings} />
    );
}
}

    ReactDOM.render(
        <HelloWorld />,
        document.getElementById('example')
    );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because `this` doesn't refer to your component class inside of a promise.  In order to use `this.setState()`, you'll need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the correct context of `this`.

```
fetch('./javascripts/data.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) {
        console.log('parsed json ', json.listings);
        this.setState({listings: 'test string'});
    }.bind(this))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

You can also use an arrow function, which will lexically bind the correct value of `this`.

```
fetch('./javascripts/data.json')
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(json => {
        console.log('parsed json ', json.listings);
        this.setState({listings: 'test string'});
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `.then()` you are using the `this` keyword, and that's basically referring inside itself. To overcome this you have to use arrow function which will refer the value of `this` globally.

Using Normal Function

```
.then(function(response) {
   return response
   this.setState({listings: 'test string'}); // which will refer inside of this function
})
```

Using Arrow Function

```
.then((response) => {
   return response
   this.setState({listings: 'test string'}); // which will refer outside/global
})
```